# Error while fetching BLOB data using JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, blob

I wrote the following code:-

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.*;

public class Retrieving_Image {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.put("user", "system");
        p.put("password", "password");

        DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe",p);

        PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from picture",ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);            
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

        rs.first();//retrieving only picture            
        Blob b = rs.getBlob(1);         
        byte arr[] = new byte[(int)b.length()];         
        arr = b.getBytes(1, (int)b.length());

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("result.jpg");
        fos.write(arr);                     
        fos.close();

    }
}
```

In the above code I'm trying to retrieve an image which is in the 1st index of first row of the resultset, in fact the resultset has only one row. But I am getting the following error:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.ScrollableResultSet.getBlob(I)Ljava/sql/Blob;
at jdbc.Retrieving_Image.main(Retrieving_Image.java:24)
```

With the erroneous statement being:-

```
Blob b = rs.getBlob(1);
```

Out of my wits.
It will be greatly appreciated if someone could explain the error.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8349906/330315 to read a blob just use `getBinaryStream()` instead

Answer (score 0):

Could you try :

```
((OracleResultSet) rs).getBlob(1);
```

Comment: @fisc OracleResultSet cannot be resolved 
  to a type

Answer (score 0):

By selecting "star" or "*" in

```
"select * from picture"
```

You are not specifying the column order, and as such, there is no guarantee that the blob will be the first column in the `ResultSet`.  Remove the star from the select statement, and try again with a comma separated list of the columns you care about.  Then you will be certain that you are selecting the right data type at the specified index.