# how to insert Blob into oracle database 11g using Vert.x?

Tags: java, vert.x

I'm  trying  to  insert BLob into Oracle database using vert.x, i  get  the  upload File

```
     for (FileUpload f : routingContext.fileUploads()){
         System.out.println("file name " + f.fileName());
         System.out.println("size name " + f.size());
         System.out.println("Uploaded File " + f.uploadedFileName());
     }
```

I  have  converted FileUpload to bytes Array by  using :

```
 Buffer fileUploaded = routingContext.vertx().fileSystem().readFileBlocking(f.uploadedFileName());

 byte[] fileUploadedBytes = fileUploaded.getBytes();
```

Now I  want  to  insert it  directly  to  the  Oracle database, i have tried to  use `updateWithParams`, but  i don't  know how to add  Blob  into  the  query  params.
thank you  for  your help

Comment: Have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348427/how-to-write-update-oracle-blob-in-a-reliable-way). It explains how to insert a Blob in oracle db via jdbc

Comment: thank you @ZeusNet for  your  answer, but i'm using  `JDBCClient  Vertx`,  so  I  have to use  `queryWithParams` to  create  a  `preparedStatement` then I can't call `setBinaryStream`.

Comment: But you could probably wrap the bytes of the file into the JsonArray?  I'm not familiar with vert.x but I would give it a try

Comment: yes  i  have  tried  to use  it  and  i  get  this error `ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column`, by  the way  i have a Blob column in the  dataBase

Comment: did you figure out a way to save it using standard vertx operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is  my  implementation  to  resolve my  problem , now I can  insert  file Blob into the Oracle  dataBase, I  hope  that will  help someone  in  the future.

```
 ByteArrayInputStream finalBis = bis;
    byte[] finalFileUploadedBytes = fileUploadedBytes;
    DB.getConnection(connection -> {
        if (connection.succeeded()) {
            CallableStatement stmt = null;
            try {
                stmt = connection.result().getConnection().prepareCall(SQL.INSERT_DOCS_QUERY);
                stmt.setBinaryStream(1, finalBis, finalFileUploadedBytes.length);
                stmt.setString(2,desiDoc);
                stmt.setString(3,sourDoc);
                logger.debug(stmt);
                stmt.execute();
                finalBis.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("nooot  ok");
        }
    });
```