# Vertx JDBCCLient insert BLOB into database

Tags: java, arrays, oracle, vert.x, sqlconnection

I used vertx 3.9.12 and JDBCCLient.
How to insert image to BLOB column?
Thank in advance

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40914540/how-to-insert-blob-into-oracle-database-11g-using-vert-x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unwrap the `io.vertx.ext.sql.SQLConnection` to `java.sql.Connection` and then create a `Blob` that you add to the params:

```
Connection jdbcConn = sqlConnection.unwrap();
Blob blob = jdbcConn.createBlob();
blob.setBinaryStream(1).write(bytes);
JsonArray params = new JsonArray().add(blob);

connection.queryWithParams("INSERT INTO XXX (b) VALUES (?)", params, handler);
```

Comment: It's working well. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped/